# Prevent local copy of XAML images

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, wpf-controls

I am setting source of two image elements in XAML. How can I make them point to same object, so that if source of one of the image changes then second one  automatically changes. Currently by setting source of XAML image, both of them maintain their own local copy.
For example, I have two image elements

```
<Image x:Name="abc" /> and <Image x:name="def"/>
```

and I set abc.Source = "xyz" and def.Source = "xyz". Now both (abc and def) have their own copy of image "xyz". How can I make them point to same image object. So that there is no necessity of maintaining 2 copies of "xyz".

Comment: Code example would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Maximus Please check now

Comment: Please be more specific in your examples. How are you setting the source? If you e.g. initialize from an URI then WPF does internal caching and actually loads the image only once and shares it between all image controls. So maybe your assumption that they "have their own copy" is just not right in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Not quite sure if I understand you correctly. I imagine you might want to be able to change the ImageSource once and have both images updated automatically, instead of setting the Source for each picture at every change explicitly. That would be the description of a Binding.

Here's an implementation of that case:

[image]   [image]

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _source;
        public string Source { get { return _source; } set { _source = value; OnPropertyChanged("Source"); } }

        public ICommand ChangeImageCommand { get; private set; }

        private List<string> _pics = new List<string>()
        {
            "/Themes/Evernote.png",
            "/Themes/Skype.png", 
            "/Themes/Twitter.png"
        };

        private int i = 0;

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            this.Source = _pics[i++];
            this.ChangeImageCommand = new ActionCommand(ChangeImage);
        }

        private void ChangeImage()
        {
            this.Source = _pics[i++ % _pics.Count];
        }
    }

    public class ActionCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        private Action _action;
        public ActionCommand(Action action) { _action = action; }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }
        public void Execute(object parameter) { if (_action != null) _action(); }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"            
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Background="Maroon">
        <Image x:Name="Image1" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="20" Width="100" />
        <Image x:Name="Image2" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="20" Width="100" />
        <Button Command="{Binding ChangeImageCommand}" Content="Change Image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your image as StaticResource in a ResourceDictionary and reuse it in all your views

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImage" UriSource="path/to/MyImage.png" />

<Image x:Name="MyImage1" Source="{StaticResource MyImage}"/>
<Image x:Name="MyImage2" Source="{StaticResource MyImage}"/>
```

Comment: MyImage1.Source = MyImage2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));

Comment: @Maximus Please check question again. I have edited it. You all  are assuming it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Image x:Name="Image1"/>
<Image Source="{Binding Source, ElementName=Image1,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}/>
```

What this does is set the second image's *Source* property to update whenever **Image1**'s source property changes.

Your question wasn't all that clear though, what exactly is your concern? are you worried about have to **copies** of the image in memory or just that they both look the same?